# Becoming non root user in ansible fails

Tags: ansible

I am trying to become a user "oracle" in ansible using the following playbook:

```
- hosts: "myhost"
  tasks:         
        - name: install oracle client
          become: yes
          become_user: oracle
          become_method: su
          shell: |
                whoami
          args:
            chdir: /tmp/client
          environment:
            DISTRIB: /tmp/client
```

I am receiving an error:

```
"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513617986.78-246171259298529/': Operation not permitted\nchown: changing ownership of `/tmp/ansible-tmp-1513617986.78-246171259298529/command.py': Operation not permitted\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"
```

I have red the article "https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"

and added the following to **/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg** without any effect.

```
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
```

**My Ansible Version:**

```
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to configure my host to accept ansible's becoming the oracle user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To allow becoming non privileged user two things must be set to `True` in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

**Important:** 
The given settings must be uncommented at the right locations in `ansible.cfg`.
It is insufficient to append those settings to `ansible.cfg`.

```
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
pipelining = True
```

To uncomment them programmatically do:

```
sed -i 's/.*pipelining.*/pipelining = True/' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
sed -i 's/.*allow_world_readable_tmpfiles.*/allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True/' /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

Here is an example playbook, which shows how to become the user `oracle`.

```
# Setup the infrastructure for Faktura
- hosts: "myhost"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: oracle
  vars:
    allow_world_readable_tmpfiles: true
  tasks:         


        # an error is thorwn when becoming unpriviledged user. Hence use sudo
        - name: install oracle client
          shell: |
                whoami
          args:
            chdir: /tmp/client
          environment:
            DISTRIB: /tmp/client
```

Comment: @VladimirBotka That may be true in most cases, [but](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user)  "Pipelining does not work for python modules involving file transfer (for example: copy, fetch, template), or for non-python modules."

Comment: (@leopold.talirz You'right. An update is needed.) Quoting from 2.10 [Risks of becoming an unprivileged user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user): `"Use pipelining. When pipelining is enabled, Ansible does not save the module to a temporary file on the client. Instead it pipes the module to the remote python interpreter’s stdin. Pipelining does not work for python modules involving file transfer (for example: copy, fetch, template), or for non-python modules."`

Comment: Quoting from 2.10 [Risks of becoming an unprivileged user]: `"... the file needs to be readable by the user Ansible is set to become. In this case, Ansible makes the module file world-readable for the duration of the Ansible module execution. ... If any of the parameters passed to the module are sensitive in nature, and you do not trust the client machines, then this is a potential danger."` The result is: **If pipelining doesn't work avoid becoming an unprivileged user when sending secrets to the remote host.**

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 or later, you need to install the `acl` package.

Source: https://github.com/georchestra/ansible/issues/55#issuecomment-651043423

Answer (score 5):

As of ansible 2.10, there is more fine-grained control over readability of temporary files (and the use of the global `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles` variable is deprecated).

E.g. to enable world readability for the `shell` module you can now set a variable `ansible_shell_allow_world_readable_temp: true` at the host level (worked for me with ansible 2.10.5).

As of February 2021, documentation still seems to be somewhat lacking; see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72264

Comment: I've been setting this in a `set_fact` immediately before the task at hand, and then unsetting it immediately afterwards.  Seems like the best way to minimize exposure in a low-risk environment.