# Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have in two Ansible roles a need to `become_user` for an unprivileged user (e.g. to set the git answers and to `dconf dump` the current settings); I have set already `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles=True` in the `ansible.cfg` file, but still have the error message

```
Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: changing ownership of '/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1613484534.333031-12971-165984005608584/': Operation not permitted
     chown: changing ownership of '/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1613484534.333031-12971-165984005608584/AnsiballZ_command.py': Operation not permitted
```

I do not use ACL or anything similar (and do not want to) and I do not see how to run as privileged user. My understanding of the documentation is that the problem should not exist since Ansble version 2.1.

I run on a 64bit aarch64 (raspi 4) with 5.8.0.-1015 kernel. ansible is:
Ansible 2.9.9
config file = /home/frank/Data/ansibleHost/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/home/frank/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) [GCC 10.2.0]

The task which causes the error is:

```
- name: write a dconf dump file before loading
  shell: dconf dump / > "{{remoteDir}}current"
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ this_user.user_name }}"
  environment:
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/{{ this_user.user_uid }}/bus
```

which runs on a Debian bullseye freshly installed (python3).

Comment: hej,
please consider: [Becoming non root user in ansible fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873671/becoming-non-root-user-in-ansible-fails#47874609)
helped me
gl

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue with config such as:

```ini
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks,timer
remote_tmp = /var/${USER}/ansible
```

Typical use in roles or playbooks is `become_user: postgres`.